# c - how to program a terminal matrix effect?

Tags: c

I have made this code to produce a raining matrix effect in the terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
char characters [83] = {'A', ' ', 'B', 'C', ' ', 'D', 'E', ' ', 'F', 'G', ' ', 'H', 'I', ' ', 'J', 'K', 'L', ' ', 'M', 'N', 'O', ' ', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', ' ', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', ' ', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', ' ', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', ' ', 's', 't', 'u', ' ', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', ' ', '9', '!', '%', '&', ' ', '?', '#', '*'}; 
int i = 0;
int index_array;
srand(time(0));

struct timespec tim, tim2;
tim.tv_sec = 0;
tim.tv_nsec = 10000000L;
for (i=0; i < 20; i++){
    index_array = (rand()%83)+1;
    printf("%c", characters[index_array]);
    nanosleep(&tim, &tim2);
}   
printf("\n");
main();
}
```

but i have a problems:

1.) the code prints 20 chars at once and wait the `nanosleep()` and not every character single and the wait `nanosleep()` before printing the next character...

hope you can help me and the question is not so silly... thanks.

Comment: That recursive main() call... some like to tempt fate! :)

Comment: Look at 'screen' library - you want the ability to control/shift columns, not line output

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see the 20 characters at once is that the program (or the C runtime which runs under the hood) buffers the standard output stream. Only when it gets a newline, or when its buffer is full, it will pass the buffer content along to the stream. This is what we call buffer flushing. There's a library function that you can use to force flushing: `fflush()`. So this is what you need to do put behind the printf statement: `fflush(stdout);`

The next issue I see with your code is that you calculate a random index which is between 1 and 83. But your array does only hold 83 characters, which means the proper index should be between 0 and 82.

Last but not least you are the first I see calling main() recursively to mimic an endless loooop. This is no good practice because your program will soon start bloating up, and finally clobbering the whole memory, causing a computer crash... wait. You didn't intend that, did you? ;) However, use a loop for this (not the crash of course.)

Comment: If he is insanely lucky, gcc might try to make this tail recursive... ;)

Comment: @BitTickler The whole thing smells hacky, but I like the idea. Obviously we have the next Trinity heading to computer business.